# Select custom values with wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In this fiddle I'm attempting to select the attribute values. So elems var should contain the values `listen,submitClicked` & `listen,textEntered`

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianfiddleuser/g2Rxc/128/

source :

```
<input tag="listen,submitClicked" id="click" type="submit" value="click"/>
<input tag="listen,textEntered" id="test" type="textbox" value="test"/>

var elems = $('p[^listen]')

console.log(elems)
```

But wildcard does not seem to be working. How to select custom values that begin with "listen" and add these values to an array ?

Comment: Why don't you just use classes instead of making up an attribute? You can have multiple classes separated with spaces, and then use `.classname` to match any of them.

Comment: e.g. `class="listen submitClicked"` and `class="listen textEntered"` will both be found with `$(".listen")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JamesDonnelly correctly noted the `tag` attribute is in fact invalid (though it will work). Also, working with comma separated values in your attribute values will make things harder once you start expanding your js.

From what I understand from your example, I think it would be better to structure your HTML as follows:

```
<input data-listen="submitClicked" id="click" type="submit" value="click"/>
<input data-listen="textEntered" id="test" type="textbox" value="test"/>
```

Selecting all elements that "listen" would be as easy as:

```
$('[data-listen]');
```

And it would also be a lot easier to check for elements that listen for something specific, or find out what each element listens for, without having to parse the strings in that `tag` attribute of yours.

```
$('[data-listen]').each(function() {
    console.log('I listen for ' + $(this).data('listen'));
});
var $listensForSubmit = $('[data-listen="submitClicked"]');
```

Comment: thanks but this does appear to work correctly as no output is printed to console : http://jsfiddle.net/adrianfiddleuser/g2Rxc/135/

Comment: It works fine for me, you just misconfigured the fiddle I think: http://jsfiddle.net/g2Rxc/154/

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the `^=` attribute selector correctly. You'd need to specify the `tag` attribute:

```
p[tag^=listen]
```

> #### `[att^=val]`
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.
>
> – [W3C's Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)

Furthermore, `tag` isn't a valid HTML attribute, and you may want to consider using [a `data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) instead.

Comment: also note there is no `p` in the code, so the selector would actually be just `[tag=listen]` or `input[tag=listen]`